# How to pass entire directory into python via command line and sys.argv

Tags: python, windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

So in the past when I've used a unix server to do my python development if I wanted to pass in an entire folder or directory, I would just put an asterisk(*) on the end of it. An example would be something like users/wilkenia/shakespeare/* to pass in a set of files containing each of shakespeare's plays. Is there a way to do this in windows? I've tried putting in C:\Users\Alexander\Desktop\coding-data-exam\wx_data* and the same with the disk name removed. Nothing has worked so far, in fact, it takes in the directory as an argument itself.

Edit: implemented glob, getting a permissions error, even though I'm running as administrator. Here's my [code](http://pythonfiddle.com/answer1py) if anyone wants to have a look.

Comment: Windows cmd-line doesn't support globbing, but you can pass the argument into the python's `glob` module.

Comment: Take a look at [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). Very powerful tool that should help you craft what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob) module, it does exactly this.

A quick demo:

```
In [81]: import glob

In [82]: glob.glob('*')
Out[82]: 
[
... # a bunch of my personal files from my cwd
]
```

If you want to extend this for your use case, you'll need to do something along the lines of:

```
import sys
import glob

arg = sys.argv[1]

for file in glob.glob(arg):
    ....
```

You'll read your args with `sys.argv` and pass it onto `glob`.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of showing how you can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to achieve this result. You can do something like this:

some_script.py:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(sys.argv[1])

glob_path = path.glob('*')

for file_path in glob_path:
    print(file_path)
```

Demo:

```
python some_script.py C:/some/path/
```

Output:

```
C:/some/path/depth_1.txt
C:/some/path/dude.docx
C:/some/path/dude.py
C:/some/path/dude_bock.txt
```

The nice thing about `pathlib`, is that it takes an object oriented approach to help work with the filesystem easier.

Note: `pathlib` is available *out-of-the-box* from Python 3.4 and above. If you are using an older version of Python, you will need to use the backported package that you can get from pypi: [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/)

Simply: `pip install pathlib2`